# Does compliance to WCAG 2.0 AA use ul tab as navigation tabs in a master page?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, html-lists, wcag2.0

I've got an aspx web application that uses an unordered list tags to parse a tab menu inside a master page. My question is:
is it ok to use an ul tag according to WCAG 2.0 AA?

```
<div id="divTabsId">
    <ul>
        <li class="home" id="elementId">
            <a href="xxx.aspx">
                            Start</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a id="elementId2" href="zz.aspx">
                            T1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="yyy.aspx">
                            Help</a>
        </li>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using ul tag. But adding the appropriate aria tags in addition to it would be useful, such as role="menu" to the ul.

Please see W3 recommendation here:
https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_ARIA_menus

Depending on your requirement you could read up these roles:

`role="menu"` : https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#menu

`role="menu-item"` : https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#menuitem